# Problema AsyncTask e introduccion de imagenes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He introducido la imagen porque es como mas claro se ve lo que me esta pasando. Cuando introduzco el link directo en el `.execute` me introduce la imagen sin problema, pero cuando intento hacerlo desde el `array` no me muestra la imagen, solo algunas. Se ve en el `TextView` que el array contiene el link exacto y lo muestra sin problema. ¿Que puede ser?

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_datos);
    resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResultado);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    //array = b.getStringArray("arrayIngredientes");
    arrayImagenes = b.getStringArray("arrayImagenes");
    //arrayUrl = b.getStringArray("arrayUrl");

    resultado.setText(arrayImagenes[1]);

    new BackgroundTask()
            //.execute(String.valueOf(arrayImagenes[1]));
            .execute("https://canalcocina.es/medias/_cache/zoom-9ed2f70fe23c1583a24e680c931e82a4-920-518.jpg");
    }

    private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap bm = null;

        try {
            URL _url = new URL(urls[0]);
            URLConnection con = _url.openConnection();
            con.connect();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
        return bm;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if (result != null) {
            MostrarDatos.this.imagen.setImageBitmap(result);
            MostrarDatos.this.imagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        else {
            imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.foto);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el url debe estar cifrado, es decir debe ser:

**https://**

de hecho puedes ver que la url que obtienes del bundle solo especifica `http://`.

Al cargar este url trata de realizar un redirect a https:// y aquí es donde se produce el problema, si verificas el status code, seguramente obtendrás un [301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

Soluciones:

- Evita el redirect (contacta al administrador) y el recurso se pueda encontrar en un url cifrado y no cifrado.
- Asegura en este caso usar https://

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso. Lo he solucionado a la hora de rellenar el array poniendole un `.replaceAll("http","https");` y funciona perfecto. Tantas horas dandole vueltas jaj. Muchisimas gracias!